# ECS CLI efsVolumeConfiguration Docker Compose / ECS Params yml

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I have a service on ECS deployed through `ecs-cli compose service up`

The ECS/EFS documentation says to configure your task definition like this to mount an efs volume in an ecs container:

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "memory": 128,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
                    "sourceVolume": "efs-html"
                }
            ],
            "name": "nginx",
            "image": "nginx"
        }
    ],
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "efs-html",
            "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
                "fileSystemId": "fs-1234",
                "rootDirectory": "/path/to/my/data"
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "nginx-efs"
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_efs.html#efs-create

How does that translate to docker-compose/ecs-params.yml syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was resolved in [1019](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/pull/1019).

Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-ecsparams.html).

[image: efs_volumes params]

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to be supported just yet. See https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/1009

Comment: Relates to 1019, resolved.  https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/pull/1019